# Python finding n consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: python

I want to know how to find if there is a certain amount of consecutive numbers in a row in my list e.g.

For example if I am looking for two 1's then:

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 4, 6] #original list
list = ["true", "true", 1, 4, 6] #after my function has been through the list.
```

If I am looking for three 1's then:

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 4, 6] #original list
list = ["true", "true", "true", 4, 6] #after my function has been through the list.
```

I have tried:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 1]

1,1,1 in list #typed into shell, returns "(1, 1, True)"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I mainly would like to understand whats going on, and how to check if the next element in the list is the same as the first x amount.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It rebinds the built-in function of the same name and thus leads to all sorts of subtle bugs...

Comment: This isn't what the term "consecutive numbers" means.  Consecutive means that one follows the other in order.  So "3, 4, 5, 6" is a set of consecutive numbers. You seem to be looking for REPEATING numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def find_repeats(L, num_repeats):
...     idx = 0
...     while idx < len(L):
...         if [L[idx]]*num_repeats == L[idx:idx+num_repeats]:
...             L[idx:idx+num_repeats] = [True]*num_repeats
...             idx += num_repeats
...         else:
...             idx += 1
...     return L
... 
>>> L=[1,1,1,4,6]
>>> print find_repeats(L, 2)
[True, True, 1, 4, 6]
>>> L=[1,1,1,4,6]
>>> print find_repeats(L, 3)
[True, True, True, 4, 6]
>>>
```

Here is a version that lets you also specify which number should be matched and stops after the first replacement

```
>>> def find_repeats(L, required_number, num_repeats, stop_after_match=False):
...     idx = 0
...     while idx < len(L):
...         if [required_number]*num_repeats == L[idx:idx+num_repeats]:
...             L[idx:idx+num_repeats] = [True]*num_repeats
...             idx += num_repeats
...             if stop_after_match:
...                 break
...         else:
...             idx += 1
...     return L
... 
>>> L=[1,1,1,4,6]
>>> print find_repeats(L, 1, 2)
[True, True, 1, 4, 6]
>>> L=[1,1,1,4,6]
>>> print find_repeats(L, 1, 3)
[True, True, True, 4, 6]
>>> L=[1,1,1,4,4,4,6]
>>> print find_repeats(L, 1, 3)
[True, True, True, 4, 4, 4, 6]
>>> L=[1,1,1,4,4,4,6]
>>> print find_repeats(L, 4, 3)
[1, 1, 1, True, True, True, 6]
```

Comment: This is brilliant, even shorter than the other one.
How would I make it so it only finds the first set of repeats.

e.g. num_repeats = 3
L = [1,1,1,2,4,1,1,1]
returns [True,True,True,2,4,1,1,1]

I've also got it set up so I can search for single numbers at a time. 

e.g. def(L, required_number, num_repeats)
if required_number = 1
then it would only change consecutive 1's to True
if required_number = 4
then it would only change consecutive 4's to True

Thanks

Comment: stop_after_match is failing if you try:
L=[1,1,4,4,4,1,4,4,4,6]
print find_repeats(L, 4, 3)

other than that its perfect!

Comment: @lost_in_code, `stop_after_match` is an optional parameter, so use  `find_repeats(L, 4, 3, True)` if you wish to enable it.

Comment: ahhh thanks, been sitting here for the last hour debugging, wondering what stop_after_match was doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

It is a bad idea to assign to `list`. Use a different name.

To find the largest number of consecutive equal values you can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [1, 1, 1, 4, 6]
>>> max(len(list(v)) for g,v in itertools.groupby(l)) 
3
```

To search only for consecutive 1s:

```
>>> max(len(list(v)) for g,v in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x == 1) if g) 
3
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense.
But I only want to find out if there are n consecutive 1's right next to each other in the list, not seperated, then I want to change the old list and change those n consecutive 1's to "true" instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what are you trying to do, but I prepared a quick, and not very good script, but it does what you need.

```
def repeated(num, lyst):
 # the 'out' list will contain the array you are looking for
 out = []
 # go through the list (notice that you go until "one before
 # the end" because you peek one forward)
 for k in range(len(lyst)-1):
  if lyst[k] == lyst[k+1] == num:
    # if the numbers are equal, add True (as a bool, but you could
    # also pass the actual string "True", as you have it in your question)
    out.append(True)
  else:
   # if they are not the same, add the number itself
    out.append(lyst[k])
 # check the last element: if it is true, we are done (because it was the same as the
 # last one), if not, then we add the last number to the list (because it was not the
 # same)
 if out[-1] != True:
  out.append(lyst[-1])
 # return the list  
 return out
```

Use it like:

```
print repeated(1, [1, 1, 1, 4, 6])
```

Comment: This is very close to what I wanted, except for the fact if the list is [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3] only the first three 1's become true.
I'll see what I can do to correct this.

Thanks

Comment: seems that it only changes n-1 1's into True.
Since for the last "1" in a line its checking if the next item is the same :P

edit:
fixed by adding:
elif lyst[k] == lyst[k-1] == num:
   out.append(True)

works a charm